# Got SyntaxError around self.async while import KafkaProducer on python 3.8.5 on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

when I run my python script, I got an error about `from kafka import KafkaProducer`.
My error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FatEvent.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaProducer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you know how to fix that error?

Comment: Try using confluent_kafka instead?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I changed the module name.

In place of kafka, for consumer, I used this

```
from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer
```

Similarly, for producer, I used this

```
from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it solved by installing "kafka-python" package .

```
python -m pip install kafka-python
```